# Can this circuit board be repaired?

Tags: pcb, pins, repair, pinout

[image]

This is a board out of a Super Nintendo game cartridge. It appears to have damage from a few of the leads, and this game definitely doesn't work when tested. The game is very rare and worth my time and extra $$ to fix. Is there a way to fix these pin issues?

Thx Stack community!
-Dave

Comment: Cannibalize a low value game board to make use of its edge card, use epoxy and wire jumpers to the damaged board. So it may stick out a bit, some games are worth it.

Comment: This game would be worth it

Comment: There is nothing quite as cute as Nintendo's trace layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A company called Pace was one of the first companies who offer PCB repair materials.  Although there are now a lot of imitators out there, Pace still makes some of the best repair materials available.

If you put the following words into Google, you should be able to find what you need.

pace pcb repair kit

Answer (score 1):

There are [kits](http://www.engineeringlab.com/circuitrepair.html) available for these types of repairs. It can be done, but you should probably find another PCB with a card edge to practice on first. My first thought is an old graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just throwing something of there but would it be possible to transfer the memory to another cartridge board that isn't damage d.

Comment: This is a particularly rare game, I'd rather keep the original components and just have them fixed